# how to validate a edittext which should be of varchar(datatype) and length of 10

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

How to perform validation on edittext ie I have an edittext where a name is typed and this name should be of varchar(type) of max 10 letters..

Comment: [check this library](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/android-validator/) it may be help you.

Comment: none of the answer helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your EditText when it lose it's focus by setting an OnFocusChangeListener  then you can do like this :

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.editText:
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
            String StEditText = EditTextView.getText().toString();
            if(StEditText.Length() > 10)
            {
                //Do Some Work
            }
        }
        break;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to implement this... ill show you what i did in my app..

this is to get a numeric value but the same logic can be used for whatever you need:

```
setAge.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            String sAge = setAge.getText().toString();

            if (isNumeric(sAge)) {
                Age = Integer.parseInt(sAge);

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(setAge.getWindowToken(), 0);

                if (Age < 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(DietActivity.this,
                            "Enter Computable Values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

this is isNumeric:(you can disregard it or change it to check for other types and stuff)

```
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and if you just want to check for length use .length() like

```
if(setAge.length()>10){
//do whatever
}
```